# Lumen Multisite using subdirectories on nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, multisite, lumen

I'm working on the deployment of a Lumen (Laravel) site under a subdirectory of a domain we're already using, because we want to keep legacy support of the current without creating a new subdomain.

I've scoured the Internet trying to figure out how to do this right after learning it wouldn't just be setting the `root` parameter (how unfortunate), and eventually came up with this, which feels so close, though not quite there yet, as none of my routes work (giving a NotFoundHttpException):

```
location ^~ /v2 {
    alias /var/www/ver2/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/v2/index.php?$query_string;

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What it looks like when I `var_dump` the `$_SERVER` information in the bootstrap is that the `query_string` isn't getting sent to php-fpm:

```
array(31) {
  ["USER"]=&gt;
  string(8) "www-data"
  ["HOME"]=&gt;
  string(8) "/var/www"
  ["FCGI_ROLE"]=&gt;
  string(9) "RESPONDER"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=&gt;
  string(34) "/var/www/ver2/public/index.php"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=&gt;
  string(3) "GET"
  ["CONTENT_TYPE"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=&gt;
  string(13) "/v2/index.php"
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=&gt;
  string(4) "/v2/"
  ["DOCUMENT_URI"]=&gt;
  string(13) "/v2/index.php"
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=&gt;
  string(24) "/var/www/ver2/public"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=&gt;
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["HTTPS"]=&gt;
  string(2) "on"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=&gt;
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=&gt;
  string(11) "nginx/1.6.2"
  ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=&gt;
  string(14) "139.182.18.248"
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=&gt;
  string(5) "49352"
  ["SERVER_ADDR"]=&gt;
  string(13) "139.182.74.19"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=&gt;
  string(3) "443"
  ["SERVER_NAME"]=&gt;
  string(13) "139.182.74.19"
  ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=&gt;
  string(3) "200"
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=&gt;
  string(13) "139.182.74.19"
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=&gt;
  string(82) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=&gt;
  string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=&gt;
  string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.5"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=&gt;
  string(13) "gzip, deflate"
  ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=&gt;
  string(10) "keep-alive"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=&gt;
  string(13) "/v2/index.php"
  ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=&gt;
  float(1440429882.5512)
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=&gt;
  int(1440429882)
}
```

As a result, none of my routes seem to be resolving, and I'm stumped on where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It wasn't `query_string` that mattered, but `request_uri`. When Lumen's router attempts to match it's based on that, but every time it would have a `/v2/` in front of it, therefore it would think the route wasn't matching. Could be fixed either in routing (by prefixing all routes with `/v2`) or in nginx.

My ugly configuration looks like this (and could probably use some work, since it's using an evil `if` statement and a hardcoded filename for the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter):

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/v2(.*)$ ) {
    set $request_url $1;
}

location /v2/ {
    alias /var/www/ver2/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/v2/index.php?$query_string; # doubled path works around an nginx bug, though I believe it's patched in recent versions

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}

location ~ /v2/(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME "/var/www/ver2/public/index.php";

    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the directory `one` is my subdir in my `wwwroot` dir.

```
location /one {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /one/public/index.php?$query_string;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        }

location ~ /one.*\.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/home/jamlee/etc/fpm/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/one(.*)$ ) {
                set $request_lumen $1;
        }
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_lumen;
}
```